# How do you make a console application which accepts commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, console-application

I am relatively new to Python and programming in general. I am working on writing a console application.

How do you write a console application that accepts commands in a terminal? For instance, like how a terminal itself accepts commands and does a corresponding task. Are the "commands" actually just functions in the application that are called by the user? Is the console interface itself just a function? E.g. :

```
def console_interface():
    user_input = input()
    if user_input == "some_function":
        some_function()

    if user_input == "some_other_function":
        some_other_function()
```

Although it is not efficient, I know the above works because I have tested it. Is this general idea correct or is it way off?

Comment: Have you had a look at the `cmd` module? I would recommend you using this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html

Comment: Also `argparse` https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: You might want to look at `eval()` if all you need to do is dispatch the input.

Comment: In general, yes, parsing the input of a user is what you are doing. Other solutions and libraries are built upon this and may add additional functionalities or a framework so you can easier extend it by without having to reinvent everything all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's standard library offers a module that encapsulates exactly the "console application that accepts commands" functionality: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html .

In that module, the commands are actually **methods** of your class, which subclasses `cmd.Cmd`: `do_this`, `do_that`, etc, by naming convention.  The example at https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd-example is a rich "console accepting commands" for turtle graphics, so you can play with it.

Didactically, you may want to start with far simpler examples given at http://pymotw.com/2/cmd/ -- that's Python 2 but the functionality is just about the same.  The excellent series of examples need a little adaptation to run in Python 3, but it shouldn't be too hard.

For example, consider the very first one:

```
import cmd

class HelloWorld(cmd.Cmd):
    """Simple command processor example."""

    def do_greet(self, line):
        print "hello"

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HelloWorld().cmdloop()
```

The `do_EOF` is what happens when the user terminates standard input (control-D on Unix); as https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.cmdloop says,

```
An end-of-file on input is passed back as the string 'EOF'.
```

(In this case, the `return True` terminates the program).

The only thing you need to change to run this in Python 2 rather than 3 is the one line:

```
        print "hello"
```

which must become

```
        print("hello")
```

because `print`, which was a statement in Python 2, is now a function in Python 3.

I find the `cmd.py` sources at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/python/python-3/python/Lib/cmd.py to also be quite instructive and I would recommend studying them as an introduction to the world of "dispatching"...!